# Using mypy to type check and i cant figure out why this errors are happening

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, typechecking, python-typing

So, i using mypy to learn how to code in python using type check from the beginning. I'm using this code to train:

```
def stars(*args: int, **kwargs: float) -> None:
    
    for arg in args:
        print(arg)
    for key, value in kwargs:
        print(key, value)

stars(1.3,1.3)
```

I'm getting this typeerror:

```
learning_mypy.py:6: error: Unpacking a string is disallowed
learning_mypy.py:7: error: Cannot determine type of 'key'
learning_mypy.py:7: error: Cannot determine type of 'value'
learning_mypy.py:9: error: Argument 1 to "stars" has incompatible type "float"; expected "int"
learning_mypy.py:9: error: Argument 2 to "stars" has incompatible type "float"; expected "int"
Found 5 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

So my questions are:

- Why error `mypy.py:6` is happening?
- How do i define the type the value for `key` and `value`?
- Why error `mypy.py:9` is hapening?

Comment: `star(1.3:1.3)` is invalid syntax. Did you mean to put something else?

Comment: Sorry, it was stars(1.3,1.3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do the below changes, mypy does not show anything.

```
def stars(*args: float, **kwargs: float) -> None:
    
    for arg in args:
        print(arg)
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        print(key, value)

stars(1.3,1.3)
```

- Why error mypy.py:6 is happening?

  `for key, value in kwargs:` for this line, you should see the kwargs as a Python dictionary. If you iterate the `kwargs` in the for loop, it will iterate ONLY the key of the dictionary. Look at the below code.

  ```
  d = {'1': 'one', '2': 'two', '3': 'three'}
  for key in d:
      print(key)
  ```

  The output is:

  ```
  1
  2
  3
  ```

  If you want to print the values as well, you can use `dict.items` method.

  ```
  d = {'1': 'one', '2': 'two', '3': 'three'}
  for key, value in d.items():
      print(key, value)
  ```

  The output is:

  ```
  1 one
  2 two
  3 three
  ```

  or, you can access the value of the key over the dictionary.

  ```
  for key in d:
      print(key, d[key])
  ```

  In line 6, since ONLY the keys are generated and also keys are a `str`; you are trying to unpack a string. Consider the below code:

  ```
  var1, var2 = "test_variable"
  ```

  This is exactly what your second for loop does.
- How do i define the type the value for key and value?

  You cannot define the type of the keys for `kwargs` but you can define the type of the values. (You already done it: `kwargs: float`)
- Why error mypy.py:9 is hapening?

  You defined the `*args` as `int`. But you passed `float`.
  If you change `*args: float`, this error will be gone.

Comment: Great answer @ErdogonOnal! I became my journey to learn python about a month ago and a few days ago i have discovered static typing and type checking. Do you think is a good practice to develop from the beginning or start to use as i am more mature in the knowledge of the langue?